# How do I specify salt version for download in Vagrant to Virtualbox VM?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, salt-stack

I am trying to stand up a series of VM's in Virtualbox via Vagrant (Master on Ubuntu 20.04, 7 Minions on Windows Server 2016 and 1 on Windows 10). During the execution of `vagrant up` I receive the following error on the first VM (Windows Server 2016) after the creation completes and Salt begins to attempt an installation:

```
==> VM24-APP-OSX-RISK: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> VM24-APP-OSX-RISK: Setting hostname...
==> VM24-APP-OSX-RISK: Waiting for machine to reboot...
==> VM24-APP-OSX-RISK: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> VM24-APP-OSX-RISK: Running provisioner: salt...
Copying salt minion config to vm.
Uploading minion keys.
Checking if C:\salt\salt-minion.bat is installed
C:\salt\salt-minion.bat was not found.
Checking if C:\salt\salt-call.bat is installed
C:\salt\salt-call.bat was not found.
Using Bootstrap Options: -P -c /tmp -x python3
Bootstrapping Salt... (this may take a while)
Defaulting to minion Python version 2
Service defaulting to run.
**Downloading Salt minion installer Salt-Minion-2018.3.3-Py2-AMD64-Setup.exe
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 1
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 2
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 3
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 4
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At C:\tmp\bootstrap_salt.ps1:74 char:5
+     $webclient.DownloadFile($url, $file)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ErrorRecord                              System.Object
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\tmp/bootstrap_salt.ps1 -P -c /tmp -x python3
Stdout from the command:
Defaulting to minion Python version 2
Service defaulting to run.
Downloading Salt minion installer Salt-Minion-2018.3.3-Py2-AMD64-Setup.exe
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 1
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 2
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 3
WARNING: Retrying download in 2 seconds. Retry # 4
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At C:\tmp\bootstrap_salt.ps1:74 char:5
+     $webclient.DownloadFile($url, $file)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ErrorRecord                              System.Object
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
Stderr from the command:
```

Looking at the installation guide for Salt for Windows (here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/master/topics/installation/windows.html) - I am pretty sure the issue is that the executable is no longer in the main tree of the older supported builds, but has been moved to the Archive section, effectively breaking the link that I think the installer is trying to run with (Salt-Minion-2018.3.3-Py2-AMD64-Setup.exe). However, I do not see any way to specify the Salt version to use via the Vagrant file, the salt files or anywhere in the code.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You could download the required version to your host, and copy it to guest at some path and run the setup from there. This way you wouldn't have to worry about changes in remote file/URL.

Comment: @seshadri_c: That would indeed be a viable workaround for now, but if I knew where to config that path in the vagrant file/Box config/Salt Installer, I would just do it there and point it toward the right version in Salt's repo!

Comment: Have a look at [synced folders](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders). You can keep the Salt-stack install executable in that path and share it with the guest.

Comment: Can you provide your Vagrantfile?

Comment: Hi @seshadri_c I did exactly that at the suggestion of Utah_Dave and although it is a bit manual, I now have all of my VM's up and running with Salt-Minion-3000.6-Py3-x86-Setup.exe installed per machine via shared folder.

Utah_Dave mentioned that there is a bug in Vagrant pertaining to the version of Salt specified. 

A link to the fix (lines 206-240): https://github.com/saltstack/salt-bootstrap/blob/develop/bootstrap-salt.ps1

A link to the Bug (lines 50-67): https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/f47773bacabfc490d457d87d9f61d6f9cb112b14/plugins/provisioners/salt/bootstrap-salt.ps1

Comment: @Utah_Dave I just updated my repository with the latest and greatest versions: https://github.com/bapillmore/AAB_CICD_SALT_POC/blob/main/salt-vagrant-demo/Vagrantfile